# Is there a way to add a Lock option to the "shutdown or sign out" menu in windows 10 and/or server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016

In windows 7 you had this:
[win7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR1Zg.png)

In windows server 2016, you have this:
[server2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c584j.png)

I know windows + L locks a computer, but these are VMs so that only locks the server the VMs are running off of.  I currently have a bat file that locks the nodes, but I'd rather have the lock option on the correct context menu.

Comment: See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2012/06/07/passing-the-windows-key-to-a-remote-rdp-session-with-windowsserver2012/ and  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2013/09/10/window-key-combinations-in-remote-desktop-sessions/

Comment: Unfortunately these aren't RDP sessions.

Comment: Well in that case you could just use the Windows key directly.

Comment: Then it'd lock the server, not just the VM.

Comment: What are you talking about? how exactly are you accessing these VMs?

Comment: through oracle virtualbox, you can access the VMs through RDP or spawn them in containers on your desktop (or both).  I tend to use the containers when I'm on the node instead of RDPing to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock appears in the start menu behind the user icon, not the power icon.
[image]

Comment: Didn't even know that existed.  Thanks!